# How can view yesterday's data in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I want to view the data of previous day how can I do that can anyone suggest me any method, I want to do this on a certain visualization, am thinking about writing something like TODAY()-1, but this will sort only the Date parameter not the Date time field.

Answer (score 0):

DAX has some nice time intelligence functions like `PREVIOUSDAY()` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634803.aspx)) that are quite handy for this sort of thing and work on DateTime columns.

You'll probably want something like `PREVIOUSDAY(NOW())` or `PREVIOUSDAY(TODAY())` in your measure.